# Gradle rkt appc plugin

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, containers, gradle-plugin, rkt

`rkt` by coreos and their appc standard seem to be quite promising. Is there already a gradle plugin available to aid creating appc container images (preferably with spring boot integration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a gradle plugin to do this.

The recommended way to build appc images is to use the [acbuild](https://github.com/appc/acbuild) tool. As this is designed to by scripted, it should be easy to create a script and execute that with Gradle.